# How to uninstall Gnome theme (including the GNOME Classic)?

Tags: gnome, 12.04, gnome-classic

I installed Gnome theme to be tried, but I realized that I do not need it. So I wonder how can I uninstall it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can uninstall Gnome Classic by executing `sudo apt-get remove gnome-session-fallback`.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted GNOME Classic, but GNOME is on HDD. Just explain how him that I delete.

Comment: GNOME is totaly eliminated.